# Why div tag is not found after loading dynamic dialog boxes?

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm using jQuery UI to dynamically load an htm file into a dialog box.
From this dialog box I'm creating another dialog box by loading another htm file.
On the load complete I then dynamically insert some html code into the #test div tag.
This works fine the first time I open the two dialog boxes, however if I close them and
then re-open, the code is not inserted. If I close the second dialog box and then re-open it again, it now works fine again. So my questiion is: why can't jquery find the div id the second time?

Here's my test-code:

Main.js:

```
function opendialog1()
{
  $("#popup1").empty().load("dialog1.htm").dialog({title:"Dialog 1",width:300, height:200});
}

function opendialog2()
{
  $("#popup2").empty().load("dialog2.htm",Dialog2Loaded).dialog({title:"Dialog 2",width:300, height:200});
}

function Dialog2Loaded()
{
  var html="This is a test";
  $("#test").append(html); 
}
```

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <a href="#" onclick="opendialog1();">Open Dialog 1</a>

    <div id="popup1"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Dialog1.htm

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
    </head>

    <body>

    <a href="#" onclick="opendialog2();">Open Dialog 2</a>

    <div id="popup2"></div>

    </body></html>
```

Dialog2.htm:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="test"></div>

    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you close the dialog, the div get's removed. Use Chrome's dev tolls (or FireBug) to inspect the DOM and see how is it changing after the close() call.

Comment: I checked with Firebug and the dialogs leaves a lot of junk in the DOM after they close. I did add a $(this).remove(); on the dialog close but it didn't work due to http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8684 in jQuery UI 1.9.0. If I remove hide effect from the dialog close, the close event fires and the DOM gets cleaned up and everything works fine.